# Returning column values using the map function - Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

Is there a way I can access individual elements of a row using the map function? I basically have a grid, and I need to return the row and column index each time I find a 0. The code shown below shows how I used the map function to return the index of the row. Not I need to return the index of the column (i.e. the index of EACH element in that row). I am new to Scala so I'll appreciate any form help :-)

```
def indices = sudoku.grid.map{
    row=>row.map{
        case 0=> sudoku.grid.indexOf(row) //this returns the index of the row. I need to return the index of the column(i.e. current element being accessed)
    case element=> element //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question is very clear, but if you swap

```
row=>row.map{
    case 0=> sudoku.grid.indexOf(row)
    case element => element
}
```

for

```
row => row.zipWithIndex.map{
    case (0, index) => index
    case (element, index) => element
}
```

Then it returns you the row index rather than the column index, as your code comment desired.

Answer (score 0):

The number of questions fromn this sudoku assignment is getting silly. And I'm not sure what you want as a result exactly.

However, if you want a set of coordinates of the zeros, how about something like this?

```
def zeroes (grid:Array[Array[Int]]) = {
for {
    row <- 0 to 8
    col <- 0 to 8
    if grid(col)(row) == 0
    } yield (col, row);
}
```